# BIOS refuses to let me select USB to boot from

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

I'm trying to install Linux (which I've done many times before), but whenever I try to select the USB from the boot-menu, the screen just flashes and it moves my selector to the windows boot. If I select windows, it boots just fine, so I assumed it has something to do with the flash drive. But even after recreating the boot-disk from the iso, it does the same thing.

The computer is a Thinkpad P1 with Windows 10 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04. I used pendrivelinux to create the bootable USB.

[image]

Comment: Could have something to do with some "Secure boot "option elsewhere...

Comment: @xenoid - Ubuntu supports Secure Boot so that is very unlikely.  The more likely scenario is that the media isn't UEFI compatiable.  There is an easy fix, create the media in such a way, where it is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the media you created. Your bios may not support the media you created as UEFI compatible images, are not compatible with Legacy Bios. This may be a likely cause as to why your bios skips the option. A compatible Bios image should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might encounter this issue, yes this is a problem with BIOS and UEFI. In my case, my system supported UEFI, so that I need to change the partition scheme to `GPT and so target system is` UEFI (non CSM)`. After this change the USB is bootable.

[image]